# MemoryError in django-rest-framework CreateAPIView due to unnecessary queries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an object using the `CreateAPIView` from the django-rest-framework. When calling the view, I get a `MemoryError`. That's probably because the view tries to present all 350000 existing objects in the browseable response.

How should I prevent the view from performing the corresponding query? Defining a `post` or a `get_queryset` method does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the `APIView` instead of the `CreateAPIView`. Here's the class I wrote:

```
class VoteCreateAPIView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        vote = request.POST.get('vote', '')
        # here some validation
        Vote.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            vote=vote)
        return response.Response({'vote': vote}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I would still be curious if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Did you find the proper way to do this or why this happens at all in the end? Do I understand correctly that here you are basically inheriting from the more generic ``APIView`` and then implementing your own post manually?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly what you say. And it was simple in the end. The reason for the problem was that the `CreateAPIView` by default creates a response which is huge if you have many objects. An alternative solution would be to inherit from the `CreateAPIView` and to modify the response and the query.